# Custom fonts in Visualforce pages

Tags: fonts, salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to apply custom fonts to a visualforce page and am running into a brick wall.  I created a zip file of fonts and loaded it into external resources in Salesforce, but they don't seem to be taking hold.  Here is the code that I have to try and reference them.  Please help if you can...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Regular';
     src: url({!URLFOR($Resource.sncFonts, '/HelveticaNeue-Regular.ttf')});
}

.callout.std-callout{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue Regular";
    color: #414141;
}
```

Comment: how did yu make it work? am in same situation

Comment: Hi Khaleel,  I did follow what the answer indicated, but the resource had to be local.  Here is a snippet:  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Regular';
     src: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.sncFonts, '/sncFonts/HelveticaNeue-Regular.ttf')}");
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you re-check the path to the font file in your zip file?
Also, have you tried using other font formats?

```
<style>
@font-face{
font-family: 'samplefont';
src: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.staticResourceName, '/Path/filename.eot')}");  /* IE9*/
src: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.staticResourceName, '/Path/filename.eot?#iefix')}") format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
url("{!URLFOR($Resource.staticResourceName, '/Path/filename.woff')}") format('woff');  /* Modern browsers*/
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
}
#content { font-family: samplefont; !important }
</style>
```